# Proving Sorgenfrey line not homeomorfpic to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ and its subspaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing

> Let $\mathscr{B}=\{[a,b):a\in\mathbb{R}, b\in\mathbb{Q},a<b\}$ define a topology $\tau_1$. Prove that the Sorgenfrey line($(\mathbb{R},\tau_1)$) is not homeorphic to $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2$
>   ,or any subspace of either spaces.

For me this claim seems counter-intuitive once the Sorgenfrey line is the real line. 
I try to use connectedness but all the spaces aforementioned are connected. I have no clue on how to solve the problem.

**Question**:

Can someone provide me hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GuidoA. Any subset with the subspace topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sorgenfrey line is separable ($\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in it) but not second countable: if $\mathcal{B}$ is any base for the Sorgenfrey topology, then pick $B(x) \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq [x,x+1)$. This can be done by virtue of $\mathcal{B}$ being a base for that topology, and the fact all sets $[x,x+1)$ are open.

If then $x < y$, then $x \notin B(y)$ while $x \in B(x)$ so $B(x) \neq B(y)$. This shows that all $B(x)$ are distinct for distinct $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So every base for the Sorgenfrey line is uncountable (even of size $\mathfrak{c} = |\mathbb{R}|$).

In a metrisable space $X$, if $X$ is separable it has a countable base.

So the Sorgenfrey line cannot be homeomorphic to (any subspace of) a metrisable space, including $\mathbb{R}$ or the plane in its usual topologies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have reading the answers. I have some doubts. You proved that Sorgenfrey line has an uncountable basis. But if $\mathbb{R}$ has an uncountable basis too. What is preventing the homeomorphism? I am not understanding the part you write about metrisable space.

Comment: In the answer above @Anguepa stated that the Sorgenfrey line is disconnected but $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology is not. Why can that argument not be used? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PedroGomes $\mathbb{R}$ and its subspaces have a countable base, but the Sorgenfrey line does not have such a base.

Comment: @PedroGomes The connectedness only shows that it is not homeomorphic to the whole reals, but we want to rule out uncountable disconnected subspaces of the reals too...

Comment: Sorry but just one more doubt has risen. How do you know $y\notin B(x)$ since $B(x)\subset[x,x+1)$?

Comment: @PedroGomes I meant $x < y$ then $x \notin B(y) \subseteq [y,y+1)$. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: the Sorgenfrey line is not connected, in fact it is totally disconnected, namely any subspace with more than one element fails to be connected.

As pointed out by Henno though some subspaces or $\mathbb{R}$ are totally disconnected, so this won't give you the full answer you are looking for.

**Different approach**: the Sorgenfrey line is not second countable.

Comment: The rationals also are totally disconnected but still a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma right I ll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

The Sorgenfrey line is not second countable while real line is. And homeomorphism preserves second countability.